Не видит папку static в APIRouter FastAPI
В проекте FastAPI создал подпапку admin_jinja для APIRouter
 project 
    ├── admin
    │   ├── admin_router.py
    │ 
    ├── admin_jinja
    │   ├── admin_jinja.py
    │   │   
    │   ├── static
    │   └── templates
    │       └── index.html
    ├── main.py

admin_jinja.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

admin_jinja = APIRouter()

admin_jinja.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="admin_jinja/static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="admin_jinja/templates")

@admin_jinja.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

index.html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock%}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('/static', path='css/style.css') }}">
</head>

Проблема именно в url_for()
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('/static', path='css/style.css') }}">

Ошибка: starlette.routing.NoMatchFound: No route exists for name "/static" and params "path".
